# Read and process 100 text files in c# in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, text, parallel-processing

I have project that reads 100 text file with 5000 words in it.

I insert the words into a list. I have a second list that contains english stop words. I compare the two lists and delete the stop words from first list.

It takes 1 hour to run the application. I want to be parallelize it. How can I do that?

Heres my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> listt1 = new List<string>();
        string line;

        for (int ii = 1; ii <= 49; ii++)
        {

            string d = ii.ToString();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D" + d.ToString() + ".txt"))

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] words = line.Split(' ');
                for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
                {
                    listt1.Add(words[i].ToString());



                }
            }

            listt1 = listt1.ConvertAll(d1 => d1.ToLower());

            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader("stopword.txt");
            List<string> listt2 = new List<string>();
            string line2;
            while ((line2 = reader2.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words2 = line2.Split('\n');
                for (int i = 0; i < words2.Length; i++)
                {
                    listt2.Add(words2[i]);

                }
                listt2 = listt2.ConvertAll(d1 => d1.ToLower());

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listt1.Count(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < listt2.Count(); j++)
                {
                    listt1.RemoveAll(d1 => d1.Equals(listt2[j]));

                }
            }
            listt1=listt1.Distinct().ToList();


            textBox1.Text = listt1.Count().ToString();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong if it is taking that long to run.

Comment: i did it with two files and list count was 1780 now i did it for 49 file and its 35 min runing

Comment: How long did it take for two files to run?

Comment: about 3 min it takes

Comment: but files word counts is different firs one had 1500 word and second have 5000 word

Comment: is there any way to do that another way?

Comment: make up your mind: 100 text lines or files??

Comment: 100  txt files with different lines and 1000 to 10000 words

Comment: How big are the files? Is that unique words, or total words?

Comment: You don't need threading...posted an example of processing over 100 files with over 12000 words each in just under 2 tenths of a millisecond. And it's just one line of code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

1. Read all words from a file into a List
2. Remove all "stop words" from the List
3. Repeat for 99 more files, saving only the unique words

If this is correct, the code is pretty simple:

```
// The list of words to delete ("stop words")
var stopWords = new List<string> { "remove", "these", "words" };

// The list of files to check - you can get this list in other ways
var filesToCheck = new List<string>
{
    @"f:\public\temp\temp1.txt",
    @"f:\public\temp\temp2.txt",
    @"f:\public\temp\temp3.txt"
};

// This list will contain all the unique words from all
// the files, except the ones in the "stopWords" list
var uniqueFilteredWords = new List<string>();

// Loop through all our files
foreach (var fileToCheck in filesToCheck)
{
    // Read all the file text into a varaible
    var fileText = File.ReadAllText(fileToCheck);

    // Split the text into distinct words (splitting on null 
    // splits on all whitespace) and ignore empty lines
    var fileWords = fileText.Split(null)
        .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        .Distinct();

    // Add all the words from the file, except the ones in 
    // your "stop list" and those that are already in the list
    uniqueFilteredWords.AddRange(fileWords.Except(stopWords)
        .Where(word => !uniqueFilteredWords.Contains(word)));
}
```

This can be condensed into a single line with no explicit loop:

```
// This list will contain all the unique words from all 
// the files, except the ones in the "stopWords" list
var uniqueFilteredWords = filesToCheck.SelectMany(fileToCheck =>
    File.ReadAllText(fileToCheck)
        .Split(null)
        .Where(word => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word) &&
                       !stopWords.Any(stopWord => stopWord.Equals(word, 
                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        .Distinct());
```

This code processed over 100 files with more than 12000 words each in less than a second (WAY less than a second... 0.0001782 seconds)

Comment: I was trying to keep the structure of his code in my solution, but I like yours better. Today I learned what .Split(null) does (though nothing forgives that calling convention).  You could also pass in StringSplitOptions.None to the split method and that would let you drop the IsNullOrWhitespace call in your where clause.

Comment: @wllmsaccnt Yeah, but that option isn't available when passing `null` - you'd have to instead pass an array of whitespace characters you want to split on (which is fine)

Comment: tnx for your help

Comment: @RufusL You taught me an obscure method call that is useful, so I'll return the favor:

 "".Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

You can cast null, who knew.

Comment: @wllmsaccnt Cool, I did not know that!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed many things up with your code. I don't think you need multi-threading:

```
    private void RemoveStopWords()
    {
        HashSet<string> stopWords = new HashSet<string>();

        using (var stopWordReader = new StreamReader("stopword.txt"))
        {
            string line2;
            while ((line2 = stopWordReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] words2 = line2.Split('\n');
                for (int i = 0; i < words2.Length; i++)
                {
                    stopWords.Add(words2[i].ToLower());
                }
            }
        }

        var fileWords = new HashSet<string>();

        for (int fileNumber = 1; fileNumber <= 49; fileNumber++)
        {               
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("D" + fileNumber.ToString() + ".txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    foreach(var word in line.Split(' '))
                    {
                        fileWords.Add(word.ToLower());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fileWords.ExceptWith(stopWords);

        textBox1.Text = fileWords.Count().ToString();


    }
```

You are reading through the list of stopwords many times as well as continually adding to the list and re-attempting to remove the same stopwords over and again due to the way your code is structured. Your needs are also better matched to a HashSet than to a List, as it has set based operations and uniqueness already handled.

If you still wanted to make this parallel, you could do it by reading the stopword list once and passing it to an async method that will read the input file, remove the stopwords and return the resulting list, then you would need to merge the resulting lists after the asynchronous calls came back, but you had better test before deciding you need that, because that is quite a bit more work and complexity than this code already has.

Comment: I would also recommend the OP learn about Big O notation for algorithm complexity: wiki link here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. It is good to know how loop operations and other algorithms run to better optimize you program.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see here that can help improve performance is `listt1.ConvertAll()` will run in O(n) on the list. You are already looping to add the items to the list, why not convert them to lower case there. Also why not store the words in a hash set, so you can do look up and insertion in O(1). You could store the list of stop words in a hash set and when you are reading your text input see if the word is a stop word and if its not add it to the hash set to output the user.

Comment: I added an answer 5 minutes ago that does all of that. He was also reading the stopword list many times and continually adding to the list of words to check from the beginning, not just the ones he had added in that iteration.

Comment: Aww man just missed timing lol Thanks for posting the answer with code.